# What is the degree distribution of synapses per neuron in the human brain?

Tags: neuroscience

I believe the mean number of synapses per neuron in the human cortex is around 6000.  What is the distribution around that average, either for the cortex or for the whole human brain?  E.g., is it normal, power law, etc.?

Comment: For a given class of cells, I'd expect it to be roughly normal, possibly gamma, but the distribution across all neurons is likely to be somewhat polymodal. You have extreme cases where there is effectively only 1 synapse, for example, and cells vary greatly in size both across and within brain regions. It's certainly not power law.